# How can I create constants in Desmos which users cannot change with a slider?

Tags: desmos

I want to define a constant to use in a Desmos graph, but when I try to do this by creating an expression, Desmos allows users to change the value of that constant with a handy slider, e.g.,

[image: Trying to define a constant for the speed of light in Desmos]

Desmos suggested doing that by [using a ratio of inbuilt constants](https://twitter.com/jrlarsen/status/473945451243114497?s=20&t=ZXX0uWUx8g_xxYuH1WQHdg), but this seems to obfuscate the intention.
Is there a more straightforward way I can keep constants constant in Desmos?

Comment: Apologies that this is out of scope. I saw other [desmos] tagged questions and thought it might be appropriate because this site welcomes questions about "Software that mathematicians use"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a helper function
$$
C_{onstant}(x) = x
$$
and then use it to assign values to your constants like this:
$$
c=C_{onstant}\left(299792458\right)
$$
which eliminates the slider in Desmos

[image: Successfully define a constant for the speed of light in Desmos]

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to restrict the domain of $c$ as such:

[image]

This way the slider becomes unusable:

[image]